# Function and vector

Tags: python, arrays, function, vector

I am just starting to learn how to program in python. In relation I have an assignment, it sounds:

*The projection of a vector b onto a vector a is a vector p which contains the vector component of b in the direction of a.
The projection can be computed using the following formula: p = (a*b)/|a|^2*a
where |a| denotes the magnitude of the vector a (and similar for b). The magnitude of the vector can be computed using Pythagoras’ formula.
Create a function named computeProjection that computes the projection of the vector b = [1, 1, . . . ] onto the vector a which is taken as an input to the function. The output must be the projection p. Note that b is a vector with all elements equal to one and with the same dimensions as a, and that the function should work for vectors of any dimensionality.*

My question is: How do I create a variable that can contain vectors of any dimension.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Your question is answered by working your way through tutorials on the basic Python data structures.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a replacement for those materials.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `tuples` or `list`

```
v = (v1, v2, v3)
```

Comment: As I understand the assignment can I only use one variable and if I use v = (v1, v2, v3) how can the vectors dimension be "any dimension"

Comment: Variables in python don’t have a type. Any variable can hold any value.

Comment: @Nicolai, sure, the dimension is conventional by your use. `v = (2, 5)` or `v = (3, 4, 7)`. if you are going to use vectors in complex arithmetic it would be better to use numpy arrays.